# Global hotkey for Python application in Gnome

Tags: python, gnome

I would like to assign a global hotkey to my Python application, running in Gnome. How do I do that? All I can find are two year old posts saying, well, pretty much nothing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Deskbar source code - they do this; afaik, they call out a C library that interacts with X11 to do the job

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. The C library in question is _keybinder.so which is used by Deskbar, Glipper etc. This link explains it in more detail: http://cixar.com/~segphault/blog/2007/1/10

Comment: @Magnus: Blog died, [Wayback version](http://web.archive.org/web/20081123040533/http://www.cixar.com/~segphault/blog/2007/1/10).

Answer (score 9):

There is python-keybinder which is that same code, but packaged standalone. Also available in debian and ubuntu repositories now.

https://github.com/engla/keybinder

Comment: Archlinux package `libkeybinder3`