# Global Hotkey with X11/Xlib

Tags: x11, hotkeys, xlib

My goal is to have a program that sleeps in the background but can be activated by the user via some "hotkey". From digging around the Xlib manual and the Xlib O'reilly manual, I gather that the correct way to to this is with XGrabKey. However my understanding of the process is incorrect as a simple proof of concept does not work.

My understanding is that if I call XGrabKey with the root window as the grab_window, and owner_events false, then whenever my hotkey is pressed the event will be sent *only* to the root window. If I then select KeyPress events from the root window, and then listen for X events, I should get a key press event when the hotkey is pressed. I've pasted a minimal example below.

What I expect is that when the program is run, regardless of what window has focus, if Ctrl+Shift+K is pressed, my program should output "Hot key pressed!" in the console, and then terminate.

Furthermore, it is my understanding that if the XGrabKey fails, the default error handler will display a message, and since it does not I am assuming that the call succeeds.

Obviously, my understanding is flawed somehow. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Display*    dpy     = XOpenDisplay(0);
    Window      root    = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
    XEvent      ev;

    unsigned int    modifiers       = ControlMask | ShiftMask;
    int             keycode         = XKeysymToKeycode(dpy,XK_Y);
    Window          grab_window     =  root;
    Bool            owner_events    = False;
    int             pointer_mode    = GrabModeAsync;
    int             keyboard_mode   = GrabModeAsync;

    XGrabKey(dpy, keycode, modifiers, grab_window, owner_events, pointer_mode,
             keyboard_mode);

    XSelectInput(dpy, root, KeyPressMask );
    while(true)
    {
        bool shouldQuit = false;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        switch(ev.type)
        {
            case KeyPress:
                cout << "Hot key pressed!" << endl;
                XUngrabKey(dpy,keycode,modifiers,grab_window);
                shouldQuit = true;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if(shouldQuit)
            break;
    }

    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your code you use `XK_Y`, you may want to say `XK_K` instead?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your program works here. My guess is you have another modifier active, such as NumLock. GrabKey only works on the *exact* modifier mask.

For example here is some (GPL) code from metacity window manager

```
/* Grab/ungrab, ignoring all annoying modifiers like NumLock etc. */
static void
meta_change_keygrab (MetaDisplay *display,
                     Window       xwindow,
                     gboolean     grab,
                     int          keysym,
                     unsigned int keycode,
                     int          modmask)
{
  unsigned int ignored_mask;

  /* Grab keycode/modmask, together with
   * all combinations of ignored modifiers.
   * X provides no better way to do this.
   */

  meta_topic (META_DEBUG_KEYBINDINGS,
              "%s keybinding %s keycode %d mask 0x%x on 0x%lx\n",
              grab ? "Grabbing" : "Ungrabbing",
              keysym_name (keysym), keycode,
              modmask, xwindow);

  /* efficiency, avoid so many XSync() */
  meta_error_trap_push (display);

  ignored_mask = 0;
  while (ignored_mask <= display->ignored_modifier_mask)
    {
      if (ignored_mask & ~(display->ignored_modifier_mask))
        {
          /* Not a combination of ignored modifiers
           * (it contains some non-ignored modifiers)
           */
          ++ignored_mask;
          continue;
        }

      if (meta_is_debugging ())
        meta_error_trap_push_with_return (display);
      if (grab)
        XGrabKey (display->xdisplay, keycode,
                  modmask | ignored_mask,
                  xwindow,
                  True,
                  GrabModeAsync, GrabModeSync);
      else
        XUngrabKey (display->xdisplay, keycode,
                    modmask | ignored_mask,
                    xwindow);

      if (meta_is_debugging ())
        {
          int result;

          result = meta_error_trap_pop_with_return (display, FALSE);

          if (grab && result != Success)
            {      
              if (result == BadAccess)
                meta_warning (_("Some other program is already using the key %s with modifiers %x as a binding\n"), keysym_name (keysym), modmask | ignored_mask);
              else
                meta_topic (META_DEBUG_KEYBINDINGS,
                            "Failed to grab key %s with modifiers %x\n",
                            keysym_name (keysym), modmask | ignored_mask);
            }
        }

      ++ignored_mask;
    }

  meta_error_trap_pop (display, FALSE);
}
```

Comment: Oh man. You're absolutely right. Num lock was on. Thanks so much. I've wasted a few hours on my stupidity today, but I think you saved me from wasting several more.

Answer (score 14):

With your mask `ControlMask | ShiftMask` you will not get the key if another modifier key is held. This sounds okay in the first place, but there's a pitfall: *NumLock*, *CapsLock* and alike all are treated as modifiers, too.

You have two options:

- You call `XGrabKey()` multiple times, once for each explicit combination that you're interested in.
- You call `XGrabKey()` with `AnyModifier` and use `event.xkey.state` to check whether the modifiers are as you expected.

The header file `<X.h>` defines `ShiftMask`, `LockMask`, `ControlMask`, `Mod1Mask`, `Mod2Mask`, `Mod3Mask`, `Mod4Mask`, `Mod5Mask` and `AnyModifier`.

The keys are:

```
Mask        | Value | Key
------------+-------+------------
ShiftMask   |     1 | Shift
LockMask    |     2 | Caps Lock
ControlMask |     4 | Ctrl
Mod1Mask    |     8 | Alt
Mod2Mask    |    16 | Num Lock
Mod3Mask    |    32 | Scroll Lock
Mod4Mask    |    64 | Windows
Mod5Mask    |   128 | ???
```

**Warning** I found out about the `ModNMask` keys by trying and I do not know if this is valid on all machines / configurations / versions / operating systems.

In your case, you probably want to make sure that `ShiftMask | CtrlMask` is set, `Mod1Mask | Mod4Mask` are clear, and the others to be ignored.

I'd do this to setup the key grab:

```
XGrabKey(dpy, keycode, AnyModifier, grab_window, owner_events, pointer_mode, keyboard_mode);
```

And this to check whether the right modifiers are set:

```
switch (ev.type)  {
case KeyPress:
    if ((ev.xkey.state & (ShiftMask | CtrlMask | Mod1Mask | Mod4Mask)) == (ShiftMask | CtrlMask))
        // ...
}
```

Comment: The value `128` corresponds to __ISO_Level3_Shift__ on my system.

Comment: On  mine, `128` is simply the `Alt Gr` key

Answer (score 8):

If you're using/targeting gtk on X11, there's a C library with a much simpler interface:

https://github.com/engla/keybinder

Includes Python, Lua and Vala bindings. (Also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302163/global-hotkey-for-python-application-in-gnome).)

Comment: What does `global with GTK-based applications` mean? GTK is application-specific, global is... global, as in: everywhere. Don't these two concepts contradict each other?