# global hotkeys with Xlib

Tags: c, linux, gtk, xlib

I'm wriitng an app in c that will be using Xlib, GTK.
I want to create a hotkey that should interrupt the application from it's activity and putting it into a dormant state.

I have done some reading and I believe I cannot use:
XGrabKey
because a window manager is running and is already doing that

is there any other way from gtk or Xlib I can press a combination of keys to send an order to my application when the application does not have focus?

I'm trying out the following code but it's not working:

```
Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
    XEvent ev;
    unsigned int modifiers = ControlMask | ShiftMask;
    int keycode = 45;
    int pointer_mode = GrabModeAsync;
    int keyboard_mode = GrabModeAsync;
    XGrabKey(dpy, AnyKey, modifiers, root, 0, pointer_mode, keyboard_mode);
    XSelectInput(dpy, root, KeyPressMask);
    while(1)
    {
      XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
      if (ev.type == KeyPress)
      {
        printf("key has been pressed\n");
        break;
      }
      else printf("event type is %i\n",ev.type);

    }
```

but I get:
Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'test' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)'.
  (Details: serial 7 error_code 10 request_code 33 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
aborting...

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Hotkey with X11/Xlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037230/global-hotkey-with-x11-xlib)

Comment: here's what I'm trying out:
    Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
     XEvent ev;
    unsigned int modifiers = ControlMask | ShiftMask;
    int keycode = 45;
    int pointer_mode = GrabModeAsync;
    int keyboard_mode = GrabModeAsync;
    XGrabKey(dpy, AnyKey, modifiers, root, 0, pointer_mode, keyboard_mode);
    XSelectInput(dpy, root, KeyPressMask);
    while(1)
    {
      XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
      if (ev.type == KeyPress)
      {
        printf("key has been pressed\n");
        break;
      }
      else printf("event type is %i\n",ev.type);

Comment: I get:
Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'test' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)'.
  (Details: serial 7 error_code 10 request_code 33 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

Answer (score 0):

This means another program has Control+Shift+"-" already bound. Try grabbing another key combination.